# Floor fuctions question as it relates to image

Tags: discrete-mathematics

What is the image of x values between 0 and 1? i.e. ({|0<<1}? Explain.

I do not want the answer i just want to understand how to get the answer. While my professor has explained this in a video, I have watched it about 10x but i still do not get it. Anyone someone can explain it to me in simple terms?

Answer (score 0):

$f(\{x:0<x<1\})$ is the set of all values the function $f$ attains for arguments in the range $(0,1)$.

An example: Take $g(x)=\lceil x \rceil$. The image $g(\{x:0<x<1\})$ is the set of all values $g(\tilde x)$, when you only have arguments $\tilde x\in \{x:0<x<1\}$. For each $\tilde x$ with $0 < \tilde x < 1$ you have $g(\tilde x)=1$. Thus $g(\{x:0<x<1\})$ has 1 as its only element: $$g(\{x:0<x<1\}) = \{1\}$$

Comment: how could i understand this when we Define :ℝ→ℝ as a floor function: ()=⌊⌋?

Comment: What values do you get for $\lfloor x\rfloor$, when $0<x<1$?

Comment: None since the floor is 0 and zero is null right?

Comment: 0 *is* a value. So $f(\{x:0<x<1\}=\{0\}$...

Comment: thank you for helping me understand better.